# sortingOrder of custom sort-functions Ag-grid

Tags: reactjs, sorting, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I use ag-grid and wrote 2 custom functions for sorting. In documentation I found [sortingOrder](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-sorting/#sorting-order). In example it is used like this: `sortingOrder: ["desc", "asc", null]`. If I add in array my own functions `sortingOrder: [() => customASC(), () => customDESC(), null]` it doesn't work. How i can use sortingOrder of custom functions?

Comment: can you provide some codesnippet with minimum reprodcable issue in codesandbox so it will be helpful to check and help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the docs, you need to add your custom sorting functions as `comparator`.
You don't need to put it in the `sortingOrder`, but next to it - within `columnDefs`. There isn't a concrete example for this, but you could try adding it to column definitions like this:

```
var columnDefs = [
  {
    headerName: "Date",
    field: "date",
    comparator: customComparator, // your custom comparing function
    sortingOrder: ['desc', 'asc'] // override default sorting order
  }
]
function customComparator() {
  // your custom code here
}
```

You need to test whether the default behavior is as expected (i.e. 'asc > desc > null' according to your custom sorting, and then you should be able to re-arrange the order using `sortingOrder`.